# Getting cookie in TestComplete web services tests

Tags: web-services, testcomplete

I am calling a WCF service method and trying to read the response on the following event -
function GeneralEvents_OnWebServiceResponse(Sender, Response, Helper, ResponseInfo)
When I display the value of Response.Text or Response.xml values into log(before using them  further in the code), the following are displayed respectively -

Response.Text
http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200/AuthenticationService/LoginResponseurn:uuid:17d10877-6514-4056-bb7f-a4c1510279c5true

Response.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200/AuthenticationService/LoginResponse</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>urn:uuid:17d10877-6514-4056-bb7f-a4c1510279c5</a:RelatesTo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <LoginResponse xmlns="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200">
            <LoginResult>true</LoginResult>
        </LoginResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, the response which is displayed in Fiddler tool for this sample run on the SilverLight application’s web service contains details about the cookie -

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 189
Content-Type: application/soap+msbin1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=9A321F31B667231925A19F3F433C24529CD9DE9283745DF8C515E12A679C63E3A0B59A7054B6157E24279965080981E9BCD632100E23B5CFDC02455BA4193552C67B2FC6E86EF258E205E04D68AF15FAF80223DE231E3C720DC295B89458888212EF1CBEC288FE5FFC70D7E22A5F932868263AA15B8D75EAAF4581652389798193D1FA216BBC8492FABF0F29906B3A5F; expires=Thu, 18-Sep-2014 14:18:22 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 14:18:22 GMT
```

How can I fetch this cookie into TestComplete scripts for passing as part of the header of subsequent service calls? Please suggest.

TestComplete version 10.10
SilverLight version   5.0

-Siddharth

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** So the traffic is binary SOAP (application/soap+msbin1). I'm not sure `XMLHTTPRequest` can handle it.

Since you're using Fiddler, maybe you could use Fiddler to do the correlation for TestComplete's WebServices calls?

- Run Fiddler along with TestComplete and use it as a proxy for TestComplete WebService calls.
- Write a FiddlerScript that would get the cookie from the response and add it to the next request. Futher info:
  [Understanding FiddlerScript](http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-07-15/understanding-fiddlerscript)
  [Modifying a Request or Response](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/fiddlerscript/modifyrequestorresponse)
  [FiddlerScript CookBook](http://fiddlerbook.com/Fiddler/dev/ScriptSamples.asp)

But I didn't try it, so I don't know if it would work.

---

The WebServices plug-in does not let you get response headers.

You can only get response headers if you call your web service in some other way, for example, using [XMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874.aspx).

```js
function Test()
{
  var strUrl = "http://endpoint_URL";

  var oHTTP = Sys.OleObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
  oHTTP.open("POST", strUrl, false);
  oHTTP.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8");

  var strRequestBody = // SOAP request body
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
    '<s:Envelope ...' +
    '</s:Envelope>';

  oHTTP.send(strRequestBody);

  while ((oHTTP.readyState != 4) && (oHTTP.readyState != 'complete')) { 
    Delay(100);
  }

  var strCookie = oHTTP.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
  Log.Message(strCookie);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. I updated the function with XML (from SoapUI tool) for my request saved into 'strRequestBody'. However, there is a blank row created in TestComplete log after running this function. 

Is it because of credentials for sending request or due to the unexpected syntax of defining request body? I have all of the xml defined in a single string as JScript in TestComplete can handle  only single line string variables. Please suggest.

Comment: // SOAP request body
   var strRequestBody = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:v200=\"http:\/\/asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200\"><soap:Header/><soap:Body>   <v200:Login><v200:username>\"g.manot\"</v200:username><v200:password>\"kim\"</v200:password><v200:customCredential>\"Test11\"</v200:customCredential><v200:isPersistent>true</v200:isPersistent></v200:Login></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>" ;

Comment: @Siddharth Singh: Use Fiddler to check the traffic from the WebServices plug-in and from XMLHTTPRequest. Maybe you need to use specific request headers.

Comment: As the below 2 headers were not there in the request sent using TestComplete WebServices plug-in AND a cookie was getting generated in the response header, I removed these two headers added eventually to the function Test(). 

Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: .ASPXAUTH=<cookie was here>

Comment: with continuation to the last comment -
The 2 headers which I removed form the TestComplete function written in JScript are still visible in Fiddler on calling the send method for XMLHTTPRequest !

Comment: And most importantly there is a message displayed at the top of Response section in Fiddler when I send a request using the XMLHTTPRequest object created in TestComplete script -

HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'. 

How can I pass the request in XML form in this scenario?